# Google Maps: Setting a new centre point using a menu

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, onclick, center

I'm pretty new to Google Maps.
What I'm trying to do is set up a map which will center to points when an HTML menu is clicked.

Am I right in saying I don't need an event listener if the control is outside the map?

This is my code from the head section:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.53562,-1.05642);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            //draw the map
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

            //set up the marker
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
            }); 
        }

        function resetMap(lat,long) {
                var latlong = lat+","+long;
                var newPos = new google.maps.LatLng(latlong)({
                setCenter: latlong,
                map: map,
                zoom:15,
            })

            //add a marker
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title:"New marker",
            })
        }   
    </script>
```

and the HTML goes like so:

```
<body onLoad="init()">
    <div id="selecter">
        <select>
            <option onClick="resetMap(53.39433,-1.25754);">Thurcroft</option>
            <option onClick="resetMap(53.41615,-1.27833);">Wickersley</option>
            <option onClick="resetMap(53.47929,-1.14828);">M18/A1</option>
            <option onClick="resetMap(53.47802,-1.06633);">Rossington</option>
            <option onClick="resetMap(53.53562,-1.05642);">Armthorpe</option>
            <option onClick="resetMap(53.5914,-0.98797);">J5 M180</option>
            <option onClick="resetMap(53.61159,-0.96308);">Thorne</option>
            <option onClick="resetMap(53.62769,-0.95181);">Moorends</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="map">
    </div>
</body>
```

...But nothing happens when the menu is accessed. Can anyone point me in the right direction - all suggestions appreciated ta!

Answer (score 7):

I made several changes,

(1) `map` becomes a global variable (placed at a level outside the functions) so it can be modified in `init` and `resetMap`

(2) the option values hold a string with the coordinates, but `google.maps.LatLng` expects two parameters, so the string gets split at the comma

(3) `setOptions` is called to recenter and zoom, you can also call individual functions setZoom and setCenter

[**Demo and updated code**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/66/)

```
function resetMap() {
    // retrieve new selection
    var latlongChoice = document.getElementById("placeSelect").value;

    // separate into lat and long
    var latlongParts = latlongChoice.split(",");
    var newPos = new google.maps.LatLng(latlongParts[0], latlongParts[1]);

    map.setOptions({
        center: newPos,
        zoom: 15
    });

    //add a marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: newPos,
        map: map,
        title: "New marker"
    })
}​
```

...

```
    <select id="placeSelect" onchange="resetMap()">
        <option value="53.39433,-1.25754">Thurcroft</option>
        <option value="53.41615,-1.27833">Wickersley</option>
        ...
```

Comment: Hi MaryAnne, apologies for the delay in trying to implement your code.

Comment: Take your time and let me know about your progress!

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement. So, I've decided to cut it right dow so the values are hard-coded, as follows:`function resetMap() {
    alert("reset fired");
    var lat=53.62769;
    var lng=-0.95181;
    var newlatlng=new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    alert(newlatlng);
    //var splitlatlng=latlng.split(",");
    //alert(splitlatlng);
    //var newlatlng=new google.maps.LatLng(splitlatlng[0],splitlatlng[1]);
    //alert(newlatlng);
    map.setCenter(newlatlng);
   }`. First I seem to get a slight alteration to the lng value, but then it still won't construct the setCenter! Help...

Comment: The above code looks OK to me, did you make `map` a global variable? Maybe that's what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put an `onclick` function in an option, you have to put an `onchange` function in the select tag like this,

```
<select onchange="resetMap('53.39433', '-1.25754');">
    <option>Thurcroft</option>
    <option>Wickersley</option>
</select>
```

You have also make sure that you include the map URL in the file

Comment: Thank-you Thegrede, altered accordingly... although it does not seem to be the issue :(

Comment: Try to put in quotes to the numbers in the onchange call, (see edited);

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean by the URL in your previous answer? Added the quotes and no change. Thanks

Comment: After some testing, discovered that the values were not being passed as the latlong` string was not being constructed properly. Now rectified but no joy... see new code: `function resetMap(lat,long) {
    var latlong = lat;
    latlong +=","+long;
    //alert(latlong);
    var newPos = new google.maps.LatLng(latlong)({
     setCenter: newPos,
     map: map,
     zoom:15,
    })
   
   //add a marker
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: latlong,
     map: map,
     title:"New marker",
    })`

Comment: In the end, I got the page to reload the map completely at the new point, using the new values. I'm not sure this is the best way... but it seems to work. Thanks Ali